# Differential equations-undamped system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> The undamped system: 
>   $$ \frac{2}{5} x'' + kx=0, \quad x(0)=2, \quad x'(0)=v_0$$
>   is observed to have period $\pi/2$ and amplitude $2$. Find $k$ and $v_0$.

Now, I know that you must find general solution and this is what I got:
$$ \frac{2}{5} r^{2} + k=0 $$

so I get two roots:

$$r=\pm i \sqrt {\frac {5k}{2}}$$

And after this I don't know what to do..

Answer (score 1):

If the roots of the auxiliary equation are $p\pm iq$, the solution is 
$$x(t)=Ae^{pt}\cos(qt)+Be^{pt}\sin(qt)\,,$$
where $A$ and $B$ are constants.

In your case,
$$x(t)=A\cos\left(\sqrt {\frac {5k}{2}}t\right)+B\sin\left(\sqrt {\frac {5k}{2}}t\right)\,.$$

Use the conditions $x(0)=2$ and $x'(0)=v_0$ to find $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever gave you this problem expects you to have learned that you get that "characteristic equation" by looking for a solution of the form $x= e^{rt}$.and so the general solution is $x(t)= Ae^{it\sqrt{\frac{5k}{2}}}+ Be^{it\sqrt{\frac{5k}{2}}}= A cos(\sqrt{\frac{5k}{2}}t)+ B sin(\sqrt{\frac{5k}{2}}t)$

Now, you are told that x(0)= 2 so, since cos(0)= 1 and sin(0)= 0, x(0)= A= 2.

Differentiating the equation above, $x'(t)= -A\sqrt{\frac{5k}{2}}sin(\sqrt{\frac{5k}{2}}t)+ B\sqrt{\frac{5k}{2}}cos(\sqrt{\frac{5k}{2}})$ so that $x'(0)= B\sqrt{\frac{5k}{2}}= v0$ and then $B= \frac{v0}{\sqrt{\frac{5k}{2}}}$.

That is, $x(t)= 2 cos(\sqrt{\frac{5k}{2}}t)+ \frac{v0}{\sqrt{\frac{5k}{2}}}sin(\sqrt{\frac{5k}{2}}t)$.

It is obvious then that taking $v0= 0$ gives this "amplitude 2". The function $cos(at)$ has a complete cycle when at goes from 0 to $2\pi$ so in order to have a period of $\pi/2$, we must have $a(\pi/2)= 2\pi$.  That is, a must be 4. Here, $a= \frac{5k}{2}= 4$ when $k= \frac{8}{5}$.